# how to get Type from object value

Tags: javascript, typescript, tuples, type-inference, typescript-generics

```
const arr=[{type:'a'},{type:'b'}]

type TypeFromVal<T>=T extends {type:infer R}[]?R:any

function GetType<T extends {type:string}[]>(arr:T,type:TypeFromVal<T>){
 return arr.find(item=>item.type===type).type
}

GetType(arr,0)
```

the auto infer is string or number ,i want to get type which is 'a'|0
i want to Typescript know function param type which infer from arr.
In other words ,how to get type from infer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to infer all types, you either should use `as const` for `arr` or pass it as a literal type to function instead passing reference.

```js
type FindIndex<
  T extends Array<{ type: string }>,
  ExpectedType extends T[number]['type'],

  > = {
    [Prop in keyof T]:
    (T[Prop] extends { type: infer Type }
      ? (Type extends ExpectedType
        ? Prop
        : never
      )
      : never
    )
  }[number];
{
  // 0
  type Test = FindIndex<[{ type: 'a' }, { type: 'b' }], 'a'>
}

function GetType<
  Type extends string,
  Elem extends { type: Type },
  Arr extends Elem[],
  ExpectedType extends Arr[number]['type'],
  >(arr: [...Arr], type: ExpectedType): FindIndex<Arr, ExpectedType>
function GetType<
  Arr extends { type: string }[],
  ExpectedType extends Arr[number]['type'],
  >(arr: [...Arr], type: ExpectedType) {
  return arr.find((item) => item.type === type)
}

const result = GetType([{ type: 'a' }, { type: 'b' }], 'a') // 0
```

**Explanation**

`FindIndex` - iterates through literaly infered tuple/array and checks whether `type` property extends `ExpectedType`. If yes - return `Prop`, in our case this is an index. Otherwise - `never`. So, without `[number]` at the end, you will end up with `[0, never]`. Indexing it by `[number]` returns `0 | never`, which is basically equals to `0`.

I have overloaded `GetType` in order to apply out `FindIndex`.

Also, as you might have noticed, in order to infer literal type, you should infer every prop of element. You should go from the bottom to the top.

First generic `Type` infers `type` property. Then, `Elem` infers
each element of  the array. And finally `Arr`, thanks to [variadic tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) is fully infered.

You can find more information about tuple manipulations in my blog [here](https://catchts.com/tuples#find_index) and about type inference [here](https://catchts.com/infer-arguments)

Comment: Thanks a million.You are great.

Answer (score 0):

```
const arr = [{type: 'a'}, {type: 'b'}];

type TypeFromVal = {
  type: string | number
}

function GetType(arr: Array<TypeFromVal>, type: number | string) {
  return arr.find(item => item.type === type)?.type
}

console.log(GetType(arr, 0));
```

Comment: This is not my intention.I want the type get from arr with typescript tips

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: It's very simplified